# Preposition TO with indirect object

Tags: prepositions, word-order, indirect-objects

Should I use the preposition to?
Are both correct?

> 1. The document I sent you
> 2. The document I sent to you

Comment: Yes: both noun phrases are OK. In 1. the covert (hidden) relative pronoun is direct object of "sent", and "you" is indirect object. In 2, again the covert relative pronoun is direct object of "sent", but there is no indirect object ("you" is object of "to", not of "sent").

Comment: The approved answer in the link is wrong in what it says about indirect objects.

Comment: @BillJ: I can't see anything wrong with that answer, which I've just belatedly upvoted. But if it *is* wrong, perhaps you should either fix it or post another answer there. It doesn't help the site for us to keep multiple versions of "the same" question open just because not everyone agrees with earlier answers.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *the document I sent you* ___ .
>
> [2] *the document I sent ____ to you*.

Yes: both noun phrases are OK.

In [1] the covert (hidden) relativised element, marked by the 'gap' notation ___ has "document" as antecedent and is direct object of "sent". "You" is indirect object.

In [2], again the covert relativised element with "document" as antecedent is direct object of "sent" and marked by gap. But here there is no indirect object: "you" is object of "to", not of "sent".

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are not complete sentences.

The verb “to send” can be transitive or ditransitive, so both of these are allowed:

1. I sent the document to you.
2. I sent you the document.

In both cases, “the document” is the direct object. In the first, “you” is an object of the preposition “to”. In the second, “you” is the indirect object of “sent”. They mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

> The document I sent you.
> The document I sent to you.

Both are fine.  'To' is redundant and I will prefer to exclude it.